# Iterating through JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, jinja2

I have a following JSON:

```
sales = {
  "February 20, 2014": {
    "services": 0,
    "total": 160,
    "repairs": 0
  },
  "February 18, 2014": {
    "services": 360,
    "total": 1109.95,
    "repairs": 410
  }
};
```

Now, this JSON has the data I want to graph. I already implemented nice d3.js chart, but I have issues getting data from that JSON to the chart. I need to somehow iterate through the JSON, and construct three arrays for services, total, repairs, and have them contain key value pairs, `{x: date, y: value}`.

So, the process would be something like this (pseudocode):

```
for date in sales
   services.push({x: date, y: services_value})
   total.push({x: date, y: total_value})
   repairs.push({x: date, y: repairs_value})
endfor
```

And the result for, lets say services, based on the sample json above, would be like this:

```
total = [{x: "February 20, 2014", y: "160.0"}, {x: "February 18, 2014", y: "1109.95.0"}]
```

As I am rendering this on the website, I need this implementation in Javascript.

Comment: why the tag python if you need this in javascript?

Comment: I am using python to generate dict and render it with jinja. I understand the confusion it caused, will remove the tag. Sorry

Comment: No problem. I saw your last line just as I was writing the solution in python

Comment: Do you need that {x: "february..", y: 160} or is it enough if it is just {"February..", 160}? If so then see my solution.

Comment: Now it should even have the mentioned structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as it is (tuples of values):

```
var services = [];
var total = [];
var repairs = [];

for(i in sales) {
    services.push([i, sales[i].services]);
    total.push([i, sales[i].total]);
    repairs.push([i, sales[i].repairs]);
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f3CKQ/1/

and if you need the exact structure as you have mentioned then:

```
var services = [];
var total = [];
var repairs = [];

for(i in sales) {
    var obj = {x: "", y: ""};
    obj.x = i;

    obj.y = sales[i].services;
    services.push(obj);

    obj.y = sales[i].total;
    total.push(obj);

    obj.y = sales[i].repairs;
    repairs.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matus Dubrava's answer, you should always be sure to use `hasOwnProperty()` in this style of for loop to avoid iterating over members inherited from the object prototype.

```
var services = [];
var total = [];
var repairs = [];

for(i in sales) {
    if (sales.hasOwnProperty(i))
        continue;
    services.push(sales[i].services);
    total.push(sales[i].total); 
    repairs.push(sales[i].repairs);
}
```

Some browsers will actually iterate over inherited members like `.length` and `.push`